# Почему ошибка TurtleGraphicsError с turtle color()

Tags: python, turtle, rgb

MAC-OS
Я делаю апскейлер изображений на python. Когда я запускаю этот код:

```
from PIL import Image
import turtle

#upscale
much_ups = int(input("How much upscale? "))

#values
turtle.Pen()
im = Image.open('test.jpeg')
rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')

x = 0
y = 0

turtle.width(much_ups)
#main cykl
for yz in range(64):
   for xz in range(64):
      r, g, b = rgb_im.getpixel((x, y))
      turtle.color((r,g,b))
      turtle.forward(much_ups)
      #print(r, g, b, x, y)
      x += 1
      if x == 64:
           x = 0
           y += 1
```

видает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yurii/Desktop/upscaler.py", line 20, in <module>
    turtle.color((r,g,b))
  File "<string>", line 8, in color
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 2216, in color
    pcolor = self._colorstr(pcolor)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 2696, in _colorstr
    return self.screen._colorstr(args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 1166, in _colorstr
    raise TurtleGraphicsError("bad color sequence: %s" % str(color))
turtle.TurtleGraphicsError: bad color sequence: (149, 112, 129)
```

Что делать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778324/what-does-bad-color-sequence-mean-in-python-turtle

Comment: Спасибо работает

Comment: Извини за долгий ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если прочитать [документацию](http://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.pencolor):

> Each of r, g, and b must be in the range 0..colormode, where colormode is either 1.0 or 255 (see [colormode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.colormode)).

Значит, нужно поставить `turtle.colormode(255)` до начала цикла и тогда всё будет работать.

---

Аналогичный вопрос на [английском](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16778390/17349246) StackOverflow.